# why used double cheked lock pattern that std::memory_order_relaxed

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I'm studying DCLP.
I don't understand. why used load(std::memory_order_relaxed).
Isn't this context the same as load(std::memory_order_seq_cst).
because load(std::memory_order_relaxed) is not reordered in acquire/release model.
Am I wrong? very confusing.. help me...

```
static MySingleton& getInstance()
{
    auto sin = instance.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (!sin)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> myLock(myMutex);
        sin = instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (!sin) {
            sin = new MySingleton();
            instance.store(sin, std::memory_order_release); // 1
        }
    }
    volatile int dummy{};

    return *instance;
}
```

Comment: This particular use of `memory_order_relaxed` because the preceding mutex locking takes care of all the necessary memory ordering.

Comment: @j6t thanks to your comment. i'mI still don't understand.
'takes care of all the necessary memory ordering' comment.

Comment: If after the `load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` we find that `sin` is not empty, we still have to make sure that we see the object fully initialized. The relaxed load does not guarantee that. But the release of the mutex when the `lock_guard` goes out of scope is basically a full memory barrier and guarantees consistency.

Comment: @j6t thanks. as you  why use say.instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);  instead of say.instance.load();

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If you are asking why `memory_order_relaxed` is used instead of `memory_order_seq_cst`, then I have explained it: the release of the mutex achieves the consistency.